# The background task I am running in my asp.net application is taking long time to execute and is getting stuck at a linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq, query-optimization, background-task

The background task I am running in my asp.net application is taking long time to execute and is getting stuck at a linq query.How to optimize the linq query or can you suggest some alternatives so that this method or this linq can be speeded up.

Linq is something like this:

```
 Litigation i = litigationsNotClosed.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id_local == d.Id_local && x.LegalEntityID_local == importEntity);
```

Comment: Are you able to log the query this results in and run it directly against the server to see how long it takes? Maybe do an explain on it? It's possible this query results in numerous additional queries, it might help to log all queries that happen before and during the request.

Comment: Not sure but try to replace with `FirstOrDefault`.  Check this question [FirstOrDefaut vs SingleOrDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69765829/ef-core-firstordefault-vs-singleordefault-performance-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure litigationsNotClosed variable is a IQueryable and not a materialized result. Try to change the code to:

```
Litigation i = litigationsNotClosed.Where(x => x.Id_local == d.Id_local && x.LegalEntityID_local == importEntity).SingleOrDefault();
```

An explanation will be posted if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Linq query use EF DbContext to connect to SQL? How do you provide the context? I think if you create DbContext in a `using` statement inside of your background task, it may solve your problem.

Comment: I am using EF only and also I created DBcontext in a 'using ' statement inside task.

Comment: if it's the query, we can't help unless you provide the schema and relations of your database. Try to optimize the query by using indexes and decreasing join operations.